# Google Cloud Client Library PHP Install Failed

Tags: php, composer-php, google-cloud-platform

I try to install Google Cloud Client Library for PHP with composer via terminal.

I already have composer in my server, and I run this code:

```
composer require google/cloud
```

But unfortunately it's failed and give this return error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\iconv() in phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Mbstring.php on line 513
```

I don't understand what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) isn't installed/enabled.

Comment: @MarcB how can I install it? I try to follow the instruction at https://workonlinux.wordpress.com/2012/10/24/enabling-iconv-php-extension-without-recompiling-php/ but when i run command "phpize" it return "-bash: phpize: command not found". I use ssh connection from my mac terminal

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

`php --ri iconv`

If it says, `iconv support => enabled`, you're good to go.  If not, then you need to install it.  This depends on whether you have built your version of PHP by hand, (you compiled it), or if you've installed it from another package provider.  Most likely, you have installed PHP from some other source rather than building it by hand.  So run:

`sudo apt-get install php-iconv`

Replacing `apt-get` with whatever your package manager is for your distro.

This command will probably tell you that this is provided by another package and will suggest you install that package.  Go install that package.